# Frequency of data points by two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have what I know must be a simple answer but I can't seem to figure it out.

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
visit <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B")
test <- c(12,16, NA, 11, 15,NA, 0,12, 5)

df <- data.frame(id,visit,test)
```

And I want to know the number of data points per visit so that the final output looks something like this:

```
visit   test
A       3
B       3
C       1
```

How would I go about doing this?  I've tried using table

```
table(df$visit, df$test)
```

but I get a full grid of the number of values present the combination of visits and test values.

I can sum each row by doing this:

```
sum(table(df$visit, df$test))[1,]
sum(table(df$visit, df$test))[2,]
sum(table(df$visit, df$test))[3,]
```

But I feel like there is an easier way and I'm missing it!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also: `table(df[!is.na(df$test),"visit"])` should work I think. To get as a data.frame just use `data.frame(table(df[!is.na(df$test),"visit"]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggregate` of base R would be ideal for this. Group `id` by `visit` and count the `length`. Remove the rows with `NA` using `!is.na()` prior to determining the `length`

```
aggregate(x = df$id[!is.na(df$test)], by = list(df$visit[!is.na(df$test)]), FUN = length)
#  Group.1 x
#1       A 3
#2       B 3
#3       C 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful!

Comment: Just `aggregate(test ~ visit, df, length)` ?

Comment: If you're particularly enamoured with the standard interface to aggregate - `aggregate(!is.na(df["test"]), df["visit"], FUN=sum)` might be simpler. if you select via `df["col"]` too, you keep the variable names in the output. But David's use of the formula interface and it's default `na.action` is neat.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
data.frame(rowSums(table(df$visit, df$test)))
```