# determining frequency of multiple variables based on multiple factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
visit <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B")
test1 <- c(12,16, NA, 11, 15,NA, 0,12, 5)
test2 <- c(1,NA, 2, 2, 2,2, NA,NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(id,visit,test1,test2)
```

I want to know the number of data points  per visit PER test so that the final output looks something like this:

```
visit   test1    test2
A       3        3
B       3        1
C       1        1
```

I know I can use the aggregate function like this for 1 variable as mentioned on this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793024/frequency-of-data-points-by-two-variables-in-r) :

```
 aggregate(x = df$id[!is.na(df$test)], by = list(df$visit[!is.na(df$test)]), FUN = length)
```

but how would I go about doing this for multiple tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `data.table` which could be useful for a flexible number of columns:

```
cols <- names(df)[grepl("test",names(df))]
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), by = visit, .SDcols = cols]

df
#   visit test1 test2
#1:     A     3     3
#2:     B     3     1
#3:     C     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `table` and `rowSums` in base R:

```
cols <- 3:4    
sapply(cols, function(i) rowSums(table(df$visit, df[,i]), na.rm = TRUE))

#   [,1] [,2]
#A    3    3
#B    3    1
#C    1    1
```

Comment: Hi! That's great however it would still require me to list every test. Do you know of a way to do this with giving something like df[3:4] for example?

Comment: You can set `cols` with the columns of interest.